# increment the version in rc file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, version, command-prompt

i have rc file like this

```
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1 
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1  
VALUE "FileVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1" 
VALUE "ProductVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1"
```

need to increment the value of product version and file version as `1,0,0,2` by using batch file.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=, " %%i in (rc) do (
    if "%%i"=="FILEVERSION" (
        set /a a=%%m+1
        set /a b=%%n+1
    set s1=%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m
    set s2=%%j, %%k, %%l, %%m
    set r1=%%j,%%k,%%l,!a!
    set r2=%%j, %%k, %%l, !a!
    )
)

for /f "eol=; tokens=* delims=, " %%i in (rc) do (
    SET e=%%i
    SET f=!e:%s1%=%r1%!
    SET f=!f:%s2%=%r2%!
    echo !f!
)
```

run like this

```
inc.bat > rc.tmp && move rc.tmp rc
```

Comment: My file will be look like this:

Comment: VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 2,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 2,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "000904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", ""
            VALUE "FileVersion", "2, 0, 0, 1"
            VALUE "InternalName", "SetIp"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", ""
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", ".EXE"
            VALUE "ProductName", ""
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "2, 0, 0, 1"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x9, 1200
    END
END

Comment: while run your script i am getting the output as 2,0,0,1 but expected output is 1,0,0,2